# String moved unexpectedly in C

Tags: c, pointers, string-concatenation, memory-address

As an exercise in pointers I made a string concatenation function:

```
void
strcat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*s)
        s++;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

Seems to work just fine:

```
main()
{
    char *s = "Hello, ";
    char *t = "world!";

    strcat(s,t);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

produces `Hello, world!` as expected. But something unwanted has happened too, printing the string `t` points to gives `orld!`. `strcat` couldn't have changed `t`. Instead, it seems that the string has moved; decrementing `t` after strcat and then printing it gives the correct string.

What moved the string? `strcat` has to be it but no idea what's the problem in it.

Compiled in tcc version 0.9.26 (x86-64 Win64) if that matters.

Comment: Note that names beginning with `str` and a letter are always reserved for the implementation, so you shouldn't name your new function that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undefined behavior:

- You are writing into space allocated to a string literal, and
- You are writing past the allocated space.

In order to do the in-place concatenation, the destination must contain enough space to fit the result of the concatenation. Here is how you can fix it:

```
main()
{
    char s[14] = "Hello, "; // 14 is enough to fit Hello, world!\0
    char *t = "world!";

    strcat(s,t);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: You may want to change the signature of your function to indicate that the second string does not get modified:

```
void strcat(char *s, const char *t)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable t, with its contents "world!\0", is in memory right after your other variable s, which contains "Hello, \0".  Your strcat function overwrote the null terminator in the variable s, and continued to overwrite memory into the variable t.

Originally, the allocated memory could be shown as "Hello, \0world!\0"
After you run your strcat function, it could be shown as "Hello, world!\0\0"  The last null terminator never got changed, but everything else looks as if it was moved to the left because your strcat function overwrote the first null terminator.

Your pointer t still points to the memory location it was at before.  Since the memory there has changed, the contents at t could be shown as "orld!\0\0".

When you print this, it is shown as "orld!"

Of course, this is all undefined behavior.  You can't be 100% positive this will happen every time, and it should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more along the lines of:

```
main()
{
    char *s = "Hello, ";
    char newStr[256];
    strcpy(newStr, s);

    char *t = "world!";

    strcat(newStr,t);
    printf("%s\n", newStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you're modifying a string literal... which is undefined. It happens to be changing `t` for now, but other compilers and even other attempts will yield new results.